# Type casting issue in Observable in Angular 8

Tags: angular, casting, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables

Hi I am learning Angular 8 and as a learner I have many doubts. I am sharing one of my doubts in detail. I hope some of you can easily help and correct me.

I have a service which consumes to Web API and returns some company details like

```
0: {CompanyId: 1, Name: "xxxx", Address: "bn"}
1: {CompanyId: 2, Name: "yyyy", Address: "tv"}
```

service.ts

```
GetAll(): Observable<IEmployee>{
return this.httpClient.get<IEmployee>(this.apiUrl + "GetCompany_test").}
```

component.ts

```
private emp : IEmployee;

getAllEmployees(){
 this.service.GetAll().subscribe(
  response => {this.emp =response;console.log(response)},
  error => console.log(error)
  );}
```

IEmployee.ts

```
export interface IEmployee{
fullName:string,
Email:string,
Mobile:string,
City:string,
HireDate:Date
}
```

I get the company details even though I use Observable of `Observable<IEmployee>`. So what is the need of casting here? and when I cast to Employee and I easily get non Employee data,it should so me some warning or error in the console right? I am totally confused about what is happening.

Can somebody please help me to understand the concept of casting here and advice me to correctly use casting.

Regards.

Comment: Could you please try again by replacing `this.httpClient.get<IEmployee>(this.apiUrl + "GetCompany_test")` with `this.httpClient.get<IEmployee>(this.apiUrl + "GetCompany_test", { "observe": "body" })` and see if it throws any error?

Comment: No error in the console.The response is still same.

Answer (score 1):

Casting among another uses is basically for intellisense to help you.
When you call this get method and pass it the `IEmployee` type, what you are basically saying is that, 'Hey intellisense, I am expecting a result of the type `IEmployee`'. So when you subscribe to the result and then try to access it's properties, it will give you the properties defined in `IEmployee`. Intellisense or the `get` method can't determine what is to be returned beforehand. So in case you also don't know, you can pass it the `any` type, which is like saying, 'I don't know what type result will return', so in that case, you can't get any type checking because the type could be `any`.

Now let's say, you get the results back and after seeing it, it looks like a `type` you already have so then you can cast it to that type and then Intellisense can step in because now, it knows the type.
So let's say:

service.ts

```
GetAll(): Observable<IEmployee>{
return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.apiUrl + "GetCompany_test").}
```

component1:

```
service.GetAll().subscribe(x => {
// x has no type here so no type checking.
// if you call a prop that isn't on it, you will see it at run time
});
```

//component2:

```
service.GetAll().subscribe((x:IEmployee) => {
// x has a type here so there is type checking.
// Intellisense can help you out here
});
```